# Need help with Zend_Auth Storage

Tags: zend-framework, zend-auth

Currently I have this code (Fetching user informations from Database then store into Zend_Auth session storage)

```
$auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
$storage = $auth->getStorage();
$storage->write($authAdapter->getResultRowObject(array('email', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'providerId'))); // store into session
```

But now I wanted to store a role variable in the storage as well (the problem is that my user table doesn't have a role column therefore I wanted to add a role variable to the storage). So how can I add an extra role variable to the storage? is it possible?

Thanks so much !

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513555/zend-auth-best-practises/5523073#5523073

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think i worked out here is my solution

```
        $storage = $auth->getStorage();
        $userInfo = $authAdapter->getResultRowObject(array('email', 'firstName', 'lastName','providerId'));
        $role = new stdClass;
        $userInfo->role = 'Provider';

         $storage->write($userInfo); // store into session
```

But unsure if I use stdClass is a good idea? any suggestion?

Comment: "$role = new stdClass;" is unused